# Android Grid View String Alignment Issue

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I am working on an Android application in which I need to create a "Tile" that holds four strings on the Top, Bottom, Left, and Right sides of a grid view. How can I possibly do this? It should look like this below..... Each little box would be the placeholder of a string. How would I write these strings into the boxes, and how would I position the boxes so they go exactly on the North, East, South, and West sides (centered) on each side of a square? I have been working on this for a while, and I just need help.... How would this be written in my java code (not in the XML file)?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a relative layout, using layout attributes like :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="49dp"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/textView3"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:gravity="center_vertical" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView2"
        android:layout_width="60dp"
        android:layout_height="20dp"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:lagravity="center_horizontal" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: How would I write this in my class file?

Comment: That's a layout file. You should read about XML layout inflation. http://www.jayway.com/2009/03/26/layout-resources-in-android/

Comment: What about doing this dynamically? How would I set the TextViews positions?